# How do I make the column with duplicate value stick close together while other value leave a space between them

Tags: php, duplicates, odbc

Does anyone know how to make value with same value doesn't leave an empty space between them while the value with different value leave an empty space behind? Thank you

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt5vQ.png)

```
ITEMNO DESC STOCKUNIT

[321B3COT4CP08002500000] [DESC Value] [STOCKUNIT Value]
```

Above and bottom stay close to each other.

```
ITEMNO DESC STOCKUNIT (Same ITEMNO as above but other column value is different)

[321B3COT4CP08002500000] [DESC Value] [STOCKUNIT Value]
```

Above and bottom leave an empty space from each other.

```
ITEMNO DESC STOCKUNIT (Different ITEMNO Value from above)

[321B3COT4CP08002500000] [DESC Value] [STOCKUNIT Value]
```

Code:

```
$table = "SELECT * FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[ICILOC] INNER JOIN [TestDB].[dbo].[ICITEM] ON [TestDB].[dbo].[ICILOC].[ITEMNO]=[TestDB].[dbo].[ICITEM].[ITEMNO] WHERE [QTYONHAND] <> '0' ORDER BY [ICILOC].[ITEMNO] DESC ";
$RS = odbc_exec($connection, $table);

while (odbc_fetch_row($RS)) {
  $ITEMNO = odbc_result($RS, "ITEMNO");
  $DESC = odbc_result($RS, "DESC");
  $STOCKUNIT = odbc_result($RS, "STOCKUNIT");
  $UNITWGT = odbc_result($RS, "UNITWGT");
  $LOCATION = odbc_result($RS, "LOCATION");
  $QTYONHAND = odbc_result($RS, "QTYONHAND");
  $QTYONORDER = odbc_result($RS, "QTYONORDER");
  $QTYSALORDR = odbc_result($RS, "QTYSALORDR");

  if ($ITEMNO = $ITEMNO) {
    echo "<br>";
  } 

echo "<center><table>";
echo "<th><center>ITEMNO</center></th>";
echo "<th><center>DESC</center></th>";
echo "<th><center>STOCKUNIT</center></th></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>$ITEMNO</td>";
echo "<td>$DESC</td>";
echo "<td>$STOCKUNIT</td></table>";

echo "<center><table><tr>";
echo "<center><th><center>LOCATION</center></th>";
echo "<th><center>QTYONHAND</center></th>";
echo "<th><center>QTYONORDER</center></th>";
echo "<th><center>QTYSALORDR</center></th>";

  echo "<tr><td>$LOCATION</td>";
  echo "<td>$QTYONHAND</td>";
  echo "<td>$QTYONORDER</td>";
  echo "<td>$QTYSALORDR</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
odbc_close($connection);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an if statement, that if it's not the same then insert a break

```
   $table = "SELECT * FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[ICILOC] INNER JOIN [TestDB].[dbo].[ICITEM] ON [TestDB].[dbo].[ICILOC].[ITEMNO]=[TestDB].[dbo].[ICITEM].[ITEMNO] WHERE [QTYONHAND] <> '0' ORDER BY [ICILOC].[ITEMNO] DESC ";
$RS = odbc_exec($connection, $table);

 while (odbc_fetch_row($RS)) {

if ($ITEMNO != odbc_result($RS, "ITEMNO")) {
        echo "<br><br>";
      } 
      $ITEMNO = odbc_result($RS, "ITEMNO");
      $DESC = odbc_result($RS, "DESC");
      $STOCKUNIT = odbc_result($RS, "STOCKUNIT");
      $UNITWGT = odbc_result($RS, "UNITWGT");
      $LOCATION = odbc_result($RS, "LOCATION");
      $QTYONHAND = odbc_result($RS, "QTYONHAND");
      $QTYONORDER = odbc_result($RS, "QTYONORDER");
      $QTYSALORDR = odbc_result($RS, "QTYSALORDR");
      
    echo "<center><table>";
    echo "<th><center>ITEMNO</center></th>";
    echo "<th><center>DESC</center></th>";
    echo "<th><center>STOCKUNIT</center></th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>$ITEMNO</td>";
    echo "<td>$DESC</td>";
    echo "<td>$STOCKUNIT</td></table>";
    
    echo "<center><table><tr>";
    echo "<center><th><center>LOCATION</center></th>";
    echo "<th><center>QTYONHAND</center></th>";
    echo "<th><center>QTYONORDER</center></th>";
    echo "<th><center>QTYSALORDR</center></th>";
    
      echo "<tr><td>$LOCATION</td>";
      echo "<td>$QTYONHAND</td>";
      echo "<td>$QTYONORDER</td>";
      echo "<td>$QTYSALORDR</td></tr>";
    }
    
    
    echo "</table>";
    odbc_close($connection);
```

Comment: Try now I update my answer. i can't test it because don't have access to your database. so please try this it should do it